# Ximea Framerate parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, aforge, frame-rate, ximea

I am developping a simple application which controls a Ximea camera.
To do it, AForge offers an **AForge.Video.ximea** library which works pretty well.

My problem appends when i try to setup the ximea camera's parameter.

For the exposure:

```
ximeaCamera.SetParam(CameraParameter.Exposure, (float)(55.55));
```

Everything works perfectly...
But when I try on an other parameter like frameRate (which is very important):

```
ximeaCamera.SetParam(CameraParameter.Framerate, 10);
```

The execution raises an error claiming that the "Framerate" is valid but the "10" is invalid:
**Error code: 11, Message: Invalid arguments supplied**

Here is the Video.Ximea class implementation I checked:
https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Video.Ximea/XimeaCamera.cs

And the Ximea documentation:
https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/XiAPI_Manual

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. As far as I could tell, it is due to AForge using an old API that doesn't allow you to set the [acquisition timing mode to frame rate mode](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/allprod/Frame_Rate_Control) with

```
xiSetParamInt(h,XI_PRM_ACQ_TIMING_MODE, XI_ACQ_TIMING_MODE_FRAME_RATE);
```

Once this is set, you can set the framerate, but that seems to only be a valid option with the newer API (xiapi.dll), while AForge uses the older m3api.dll.

When not using frame rate mode, the camera framerate is set by exposure time. For example, setting an exposure time of 0.1s sets the framerate to 10 Hz. If you want to control them separately, then it might mean some tinkering to enable AForge to interact with the newer API.